# What's the default compression level of image.Save()?

Tags: c#, image-processing

What's `Image.save()` default compression level and what's the default quality of the output image after saving it?

Comment: You could check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957477/what-quality-level-does-image-save-use-for-jpeg-files

Comment: Refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12298515/best-format-for-lossless-image-compression-in-c-sharp